# Как определить имя файла из которого вызвана функция?

Tags: javascript

Я нашёл искомое в

> function.caller.arguments[3]

Но это не документировано и в любой момент может "отвалиться".
Есть нормальный путь?

Comment: Можно через stacktrace (new Error().stack) в вызываемой функции, но такой подход используемый на постоянной основе означает, что вы делаете что-то неправильно, функция не стандартна согласно [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). Для дебага лучше используйте деббагер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взято с https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697791/nodejs-get-filename-of-caller-function

```js
function _getCallerFile() {
    try {
        var err = new Error();
        var callerfile;
        var currentfile;

        Error.prepareStackTrace = function (err, stack) { return stack; };

        currentfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

        while (err.stack.length) {
            callerfile = err.stack.shift().getFileName();

            if(currentfile !== callerfile) return callerfile;
        }
    } catch (err) {}
    return undefined;
}
```